# Forcing Visual Studio to set "Insert Tabs" from a script

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, spaces

I would like to write a script to force Visual Studio 2015 to "Insert Tabs".  The idea is that this script would be pushed out by our IT department and run on Windows startup to ensure that everyone is consistent.  If you hate tabs, pretend I'd like to write a script to set "Insert Spaces".

The obvious way might seem to set HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Visual Studio\14.0\Text Editor\CSharp\Insert Tabs to 1.  This appears to do nothing, probably because we are using Synchronized Settings (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn135229.aspx).  What can I do about this, short of writing an extension to Visual Studio and pushing THAT out.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using an extension like [EditorConfig](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8bccfe2-650c-4b42-bc5c-845e21f96328) or [Rebracer](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/410e9b9f-65f3-4495-b68e-15567e543c58) that apply editor settings from a shared per-solution file.